# Getting an error on update

Tags: updates, release-juno, apt, laptop

I am running eos `juno` on a razer blade late 2016 model [laptop](/questions/tagged/laptop). I tried to do a `sudo apt-get update` && `upgrade` on terminal

```
Err:13 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 Packages             
  Hash Sum mismatch
  Hashes of expected file:
   - Filesize:396740 [weak]
   - SHA256:869bb9c17b16319836d7a130aac89e549eeb7488657b6374c19884b689a487c5
   - SHA1:dff8b40c44ef805efcf589ba33a916f7f88c38da [weak]
   - MD5Sum:f91b2998ad4c92a55f05838802d0a456 [weak]
  Hashes of received file:
   - SHA256:3bb6e57d5b785359e3004a22f92a10288522dcb59b50dc4f7c456f212869a2d0
   - SHA1:1d46dffcdce50fd18f9d2d8d0a799ff09d8802c3 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:05bbf3f0beb7304ace1596f15357954d [weak]
   - Filesize:396740 [weak]
  Last modification reported: Tue, 04 Dec 2018 01:28:06 +0000
  Release file created at: Tue, 04 Dec 2018 01:27:51 +0000 
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK this happens when repositories are about or in the middle of their refreshment, you just got bad timing

- To fix it just run:

  - `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*`
- The you can run

  - `sudo apt update`

---

To explain the solution

You'll remove the repo index and release files from your system. Those are updated every time you run `sudo apt update`

Then when you run the update they'll get populated, this time valid

Now you can continue using [apt](/questions/tagged/apt)